# Azure function post call resulting in 400 bad request with ajax call and same function works when POST is changed to GET

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to make an ajax call to azure function which is saving the data to cosmos db on azure portals.

Not works :

```
var dataArray = {
    task:"abcd",
    name:"efg",
    dDoB:"20/12/2018",
    dCountry:"America"
  };

    $.post('https://functionget.azurewebsites.net/api/***/code**', dataArray ,
    function(data,status) {
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);

  });
```

Works :

```
var dataArray = {
    task:"abcd",
    name:"efg",
    dDoB:"20/12/2018",
    dCountry:"America"
  };

    $.get('https://functionget.azurewebsites.net/api/***/code**', dataArray ,
    function(data,status) {
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);

  });
```

Here is my azure function code :

module.exports = async function (context, req) {

```
// We need both name and task parameters.
if (req.query.name && req.query.task) {

    // Set the output binding data from the query object.
    context.bindings.taskDocument = req.query;

    // Success.
    context.res = {
        status: 200
    };
}
else {
    context.res = {
        status: 400,
        body: "The query options 'name' and 'task' are required"
    };
}
```

};

when we look for the network in console for both the request then GET sends parameters in query string and post in form data.Can someone please let me know how to send post call with parameters to azure function through ajax call.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your function accept form-data? It's better if you could share azure function code.

Comment: @JerryLiu  updated my question with azure function code.can you please have a look at it and suggest on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax post `dataArray` as form data rather than query string, so with `req.query.xx` we are not able to receive data as expected. We can post a Json and read `req.body`. Check code below.

For Function, change `query` to `body`.

```
if (req.body.name && req.body.task) {

    context.bindings.taskDocument = req.body;
    ...
}
```

For ajax, use `$.ajax` instead of `$.post` to send Json.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<functionurl>",
  data: JSON.stringify(dataArray),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(data,status) {
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  }
});
```